# Import old PyCharm XML-based color scheme into latest PyCharm

Tags: intellij-idea, colors, pycharm

I made a custom color scheme a while back and saved it as XML file. Typically I would drop this into the ~/Library/Preferences/PyCharm*/colors directory, but more recent versions do not have this directory.

How can I import this color scheme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New color schemes have `.icls` extension and are placed in the same directory as before (`colors` subdirectory of the [config](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519) directory).

If you don't have this directory, it means you don't have any custom color schemes. Try modifying a default one and save it under a different name and it should appear at the specified location.